# logout and session false in termination of android app without using logout button

Tags: java, android

I want to logout and session false in termination of android app without using logout button

termination of android app when the user without clicks on the log out button, I want to logout and kill the current session. How can this be done please?

**this is my session class**

```
    public class Session {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;

    public Session(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        preferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("Novel Traveller",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor =preferences.edit();
    }

    public void  setLoggedin(boolean loggedin){
        editor.putBoolean("Logged In mode",loggedin);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public boolean loggedIn(){
        return preferences.getBoolean("Logged In mode",false);
    }
}
```

**this is main activity**

```
    enter code here

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Session session;

    public static final String NOTE_ID_EXTAR = "com.text.traveller.novel_traveller_application.Note Identifier";
    public static final String NOTE_TITLE_EXTAR = "com.text.traveller.novel_traveller_application.Note Title";
    public static final String NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTAR = "com.text.traveller.novel_traveller_application.Note Message";
    public static final String NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTAR = "com.text.traveller.novel_traveller_application.Note Category";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnLogout =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        session = new Session(this);
        if(!session.loggedIn()){
            logout();
        }
        btnLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
            }
        });
    }
    private void logout(){
        session.setLoggedin(false);
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,loginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create logout method in your my session class like:

```
 public void logout() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }
```

and override onStop() method in your Activity and just write:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {   
super.onStop(); 
session.setLoggedin(false);
session.logout();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try on this